# What is /citrix/xenapp/auth/login.aspx

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.Net webform website that uses SQL Membership for authentication and login. The user's password are encrypted.

In my project I save all exceptions when they happened in a database. 
Yesterday I have got this exception which is very wired and I do know about it.
I am assuming that somebody was trying to hack the website.

**Error:** Global.asax: www.Example.com/**citrix/xenapp/auth**/login.aspx?**CTX_MessageType=WARNING&CTX_MessageKey=NoUsableClientDetected**

I have this URL: www.Example.com/login.aspx but why somebody did this citrix/xenapp/auth/login.aspx  with some Querystrings.

If it was an attack the SQL Membership is secure enough?
If you have any idea please let me know before something happened.

Thanks

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Either someone mis-typed an URL, or more likely, someone was probing your website to see if Citrix XenApp is installed. If it installed, it would probably attempt to make an automated attack on your site.

Comment: What is Citrix XenApp? Why should I have this one for ASP.Net Web Forms?